# GraphQL { "message": "booking is not defined", "locations": [ { "line": 6, "column": 21 } ], "path": [ "bookings", 0, "event" ] }

Tags: javascript, mongodb, graphql, bind, resolver

I am fairly new to GraphQL, and I am having trouble reading the errors.

#1. I don't know how to locate this error ( find the line and column).

#2. "booking is not defined" I am having a hard time finding what causes the trouble.

This is the query from front end:

```js
//this is the query from the client

fetchedBookedEventQuery : {
        query:`
            query {
                bookings {
                _id
                createdAt
                    event {
                        _id
                        title
                        date
                    }
                }
            }
        `
    },
```

back end structure:

```js
// Booking Resolver 



bookings:async (args, req)=>{
        //adds protected route
        if(!req.isAuth){ throw new Error('Not authenticated!') }


        console.log('you are fetching bookings')
        try{
        const bookings = await Booking.find()

        
        const newRes = bookings.map(each =>  transformBooking(each) )
        
        console.log('bookings:', newRes)
    
        return newRes
        }catch(err) {
            console.log('Err! ****************', err)
            throw err}
    },
    
    
// merge data resolver


// function to populate the booking
const transformBooking = booking =>{
    
    const obj1 = booking 


    // I replace booking with obj1, in eforts to troubleshoot

    return{

        ...booking._doc,
        _id: booking.id,
        user: user.bind(this, obj1.user),
        event: singleEvent.bind(this, obj1.event),
        createAt:booking._doc.createAt,
        updatedAt:booking._doc.updatedAt,
    }
}
```

Response on backend:

```js
{}
{
  query: '\n' +
    '            query {\n' +
    '                bookings {\n' +
    '                _id\n' +
    '                createdAt\n' +
    '                    event {\n' +
    '                        _id\n' +
    '                        title\n' +
    '                        date\n' +
    '                    }\n' +
    '                }\n' +
    '            }\n' +
    '        '
}



you are fetching bookings



bookings: [
  {
    _id: '61e21bcfed8572f550c31dfb',
    event: [Function: bound singleEvent] AsyncFunction,
    user: [Function: bound user] AsyncFunction,
    createdAt: 2022-01-15T00:56:47.582Z,
    updatedAt: 2022-01-15T00:56:47.582Z,
    __v: 0,
    createAt: undefined
  },
  {
    _id: '61e21beded8572f550c31dfe',
    event: [Function: bound singleEvent] AsyncFunction,
    user: [Function: bound user] AsyncFunction,
    createdAt: 2022-01-15T00:57:17.684Z,
    updatedAt: 2022-01-15T00:57:17.684Z,
    __v: 0,
    createAt: undefined
  }
]
```

No error!

response on front end  /  or http://localhost:5000/graphql:

```js
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "booking is not defined",
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 5,
          "column": 21
        }
      ],
      "path": [
        "bookings",
        0,
        "event"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "data": null
}
```

Comment: Might it be that your "booking" vard in the transform function is undefined/null sometimes?

Comment: According to your logs, you're trying to call `booking` instead of `bookings` when you use your frontend, is that intended?

Comment: This is the whole confusion I have, I don't see booking anywhere:
@ Mentlegen:

I am running this query  just from back end using "graphiql",
 and I am getting this error about booking, initially I though the "user.bind(this, obj1.user)" is failing.
But other than that I don't see where I count be, maybe the schema?

Thank you for your help, If you like I can share the gitHub repo with you.

@ SkyzohKey: That is what I thought, but I only get this error, it never get through. Is there any way to check what : event: [Function: bound singleEvent] AsyncFunction is actually retrieving?

Comment: The repo is here:  https://github.com/John-v77/graphQL-react_app